# Title for charts and axes in dimple.js charts

Tags: charts, dimple.js

how to add a title to the dimple.js charts?
I want to update title of my charts and axes. I am using dimple.js. Please advise.

Comment: The examples provided on the home page at http://dimplejs.org/ already have titles on the axes.  I would imagine that a chart title is simply a div above the chart.

Comment: Thanks @Robert but I am just using a header tag at present for the title. But I am looking if there is an API command with built in spacing, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a title with a little d3.  Here's an example for a centre title.  For simplicity I've put styling in d3 but it would probably be neater to give it a class and set the styles in css:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", c._xPixels() + c._widthPixels() / 2)
   .attr("y", c._yPixels() - 20)
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .style("font-weight", "bold")
   .text("My brilliant chart about a and b");
```

http://jsbin.com/hosobo/4/edit?js,output

Comment: thanks a lot @John. Also noticed that I had the older version of the dimple.js URL. It works for me now.

Comment: what is the c variable?

Answer (score 2):

John's answer is awesome, but couldn't you use the dimple function for titleShape?  If you are defining your axes as "x" and "y", then you could just do:

```
x.titleShape.text("your x axis title");
y.titleShape.text("your y axis title");
```

if you're not defining axes then using d3 like John showed is probably the best way.

Comment: Yes, this answers the second part of the question which I didn't cover, you can set custom axis titles like this.  My answer above was just for the main chat title.  In fact the latest release of dimple simplifies custom axis titles slightly.  You can now set them before drawing with `x.title = "your x axis title");` for example. https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#title

Comment: Here's an example of using the `axis.title` property to set custom titles: http://jsbin.com/hosobo/6/edit?js,output

Comment: ah, i didn't catch that. adding a title to the svg itself is totally useful.  thanks